# insert into database MySQL Django

Tags: django, django-models

My data is not being saved inside the DB.

Here is my **views.py** file

```
def rr_reply(request):


    cc_user = request.user.id
    conversation_id = request.GET.get('conversation_id','')
    b_id = request.GET.get('b_id','')


    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = CcReply(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            reply = form.cleaned_data['reply']

            queries = WebQuery.objects.using('launchg').filter(conversation_id = conversation_id)

            for query in queries:
                q_id = query.query_id               

            cc_chat_data_obj = CcChatData(conversation_id = conversation_id , reply_from = request.user.id , 
                b_id = b_id, q_id = q_id)
            web_reply_obj = WebReply(query_id = q_id, conversation_id = conversation_id , b_id = b_id, 
                u_query = reply , date_time = date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),diff = 0)

            cc_chat_data_obj.save()
            web_reply_obj.save()


    else:
        form = CcReply()
```

Comment: are you sure the `form.is_valid()`?

Comment: Yes. The form is valid .Prints `True` when the form is submitted.

Comment: Any suggestions please!!!

Comment: Have you overridden `save()` on CcChatData and WebReply?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 cc_chat_data_obj = CcChatData.objects.create(conversation_id = conversation_id , reply_from = request.user.id , b_id = b_id, q_id = q_id)
 web_reply_obj = WebReply.objects.create(query_id = q_id, conversation_id = conversation_id , b_id = b_id, u_query = reply , date_time = date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),diff = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your form is indeed valid? (is_valid)

Your current code does nothing when the form isn't valid.

Comment: Yes. The form is valid .Prints True when the form is submitted.
Any suggestions please!!!